# Pascal readkey command issue

Tags: pascal

I use readkey command twice.
It works fine on the first time but refuses to work in the second one.
I'd like that program waits for my key press but the program ends itself.

code:

```
program window1;

uses crt;

var x,y:integer;

begin

clrscr;
window(1,1,80,25);
readkey;

//writting just window borders
for x:=1 to 80 do
 for y:=1 to 25 do
 begin
   if (x >= 2) and (x <= 79) and
      (y >= 2) and (y <= 24) then
     continue
   else
     begin
       gotoxy(x,y);
       write('*');
     end;
 end;

gotoxy(2,23);
write('inside window press any key to exit...');
readkey;
//readln;

end.
```

I've pressed the up arrow key.

Comment: When you say "refuses to work" what exactly do you mean, e.g. that the window closes before you have a chance to press a key, or that windows stays on-screen and doesn't close, as it should, the second time you press a key?  I tried your program in Lazarus, the IDE for Free Pascal and it works fine:  it clears the screen and waits for me to press a key, then it draws your window, write the 'Inside window ...' message and waits until I press a key and then it closes, so it works fine for me.

Comment: This: that the window closes before you have a chance to press a key.
The program finishes its execution after running with Ctrl+F9 and back to the FPC editor.
I'm coding using FPC from CMD (of windows 10) as administrator.

Comment: Which button(s) do you press first (in response to the first `ReadKey`)? Have you read the description about `ReadKey` in the documentation?

Comment: I've pressed the up arrow key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I've pressed the up arrow key

Some keys on a keyboard generates what is called extended keys. The arrow keys (among others) are such keys. They return two characters, not one. The first character is ASCII 0 and the second is the scan code of the pressed key.

For `ReadKey` it is [documented](https://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/rtl/crt/readkey.html):

> ReadKey reads 1 key from the keyboard buffer, and returns this. If an extended or function key has been pressed, then the zero ASCII code is returned. You can then read the scan code of the key with a second ReadKey call.

I could add to that, that `ReadKey` waits for input if the keyboard buffer is empty (but only if it is empty).

Therefore, when your program calls `ReadKey` for the first time, and you hit the "up arrow key", two bytes are put into the buffer, $00 and $48. The first one ($00) is returned to your code, and the scan code for the up arrow remains in the input buffer. When you then later call `ReadKey` a second time it receives the scan code from the buffer and continues immediately without stopping for input.

You can deal with this in one of two ways:

1.Write a procedure, say `WaitForAnyKey` that deals with the extended keys:

```
procedure WaitForAnyKey;
var
  c: char;
begin
  c:=ReadKey;
  if c=#0 then
    c:=ReadKey;
end;
```

and you call it instead of calling `ReadKey` directly.

2.Write a procedure that waits for, and accepts a specific key only:

```
procedure WaitForCR; // wait for CR, Carriage Return (Enter)
const
  CR=#13;
var
  c: Char;
begin
  repeat
    c:=ReadKey;
  until c=CR;
end
```

and you call it instead of calling `ReadKey` directly.

Comment: Beware of "accepts a specific key only": if an extended key sends #0 #13...

Comment: Thanks @lin but I don't think that is a valid concern as the key with scancode 13 represents printable characters and is therefore not sent as a #00#13.

Comment: You guys are the best! Good solution! It works fine! I used that procedure WaitForAnyKey;

Comment: @TomBrunberg you are right; but from your example with codes $0 and $48, the simple algorithm would fail to wait for an "H" (ascii $48) because it does not "remember" whether the key was extended or not.

Comment: @linuxfan now you are right (and you were from the beginning). Guarding for such an error becomes rather messy. Something like checking for #0, and if so, read once more, but throw it away. I'll think about it.